# Index not working in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im trying to get values for onchange in fileupload to use in controller.

```
  <span id="ind">{{$index}}</span>
  <input id="PhotoPicker" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" title="{{JobDetail.Id}}" alt="{{$index}}" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)" /></div>
```

Here,In the `span ind` i cant able to get the row index. When i use it in `alt` its not working. I can able to get the `title` too. In `alt` it always shows zero.

```
 $scope.file_changed = function (element) {
    debugger;

    var filesSelected = element.files;
    var JobDetailId = element.title; //working
    var index = element.alt; //not working
   };
```

Kindly help me!

Comment: $index will work only together with ng-repeat

Comment: Im already in a ng-repeat thats why index works in span.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that angular will only give you the files attribute because your input is of type file. You should use angular.attr() for others attribute, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

By the way i think this :

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_changed(this)"
```

Can be rewritten to :

```
onchange="file_changed(this)"
```

You might consider using this module : https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But here title and span is working fine. My intention is to take that index not alt. Kindly  give me a sample for  angular.attr().